# Meteor event keypress not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to get the input text dynamically

Template:

```
<template name="search">

<div class="searchbox">
<input class="form-control input-lg search" type="text"    placeholder="Search">
</div>

</template>
```

Event:

```
Template.search.events({

'ḱeypress input' : function(event, template) {

    console.log("BITE");
    }
});
```

But it's just not working (tested with Firefox and Chrome).
The same with keyup and keydown

Comment: Is the diacritical mark on `ḱeypress` intentional?

Comment: ok, it was a tipo on keypress.